# Jquery ajax insert statement

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, insert

I am currently trying to work with jquery Ajax but having a little problam and will be glad to receive a little help!.

I want to insert data into the database using jquery ajax and a web service.

my html looks like this :

```
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.intellisense.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loadingPanel").hide();
    $("#submitBtn").click(function() {
      var fName = $("#fnameTextBox").val();
      var lName = $("#lnameTextBox").val();
      var Age = $("#ageTextBox.ClientID").val();
      $("#loadingPanel").show();

      $.ajax({
        url: "demoService.asmx/addInfo",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({
          "fName": fName,
          "lName": lName,
          "Age": Age
        }),
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.d == "success") {
            alert("Data saved");
            var firstName = $('#<%=fnameTextBox.ClientID%>').val('');
            var lastName = $('#<%=lnameTextBox.ClientID%>').val('');
            var age = $('#<%=ageTextBox.ClientID%>').val('');

          }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(thrownError);
        }
      }).done(function() {
        $("#loadingPanel").hide();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fnameTextBox" Width="200px" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="lnameTextBox" Width="200px" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td>
              <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ageTextBox" Width="200px" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" />
              <div id="loadingPanel" style="color:green; font-weight:bold;">Data saving...</div>
            </td>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

my web service like this

```
  [WebMethod]
        public string addInfo(string fName, string lName, int Age)
        {
            string status = "";

            infoTable info = new infoTable {FirstName = fName, LastName = lName, age = Age };

            using(demoDBEntities demoEntity = new demoDBEntities())
            {
                demoEntity.infoTable.Add(info);
                demoEntity.SaveChanges();
                status = "success";
            }

            return status;
        }
```

When I press the submit button and internal server error occurs, when I see the inner exception, it says that the parameter fName was not supplied, although I typed in a namne in the text box. any help please?

the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: missing parameter: fName.
System.Web.Services.Protocols.ValueCollectionParameterReader.Read(NameValueCollection collection)
   System.Web.Services.Protocols.UrlParameterReader.Read(HttpRequest request)
System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.ReadParameters()
  System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
```

Comment: Please don't post code dumps in comments... [edit] the question and update it there...

Comment: Try removing your wrapping `JSON.stringify({ })` around your parameters and just leave the parameter declarations.

Comment: have you used `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` in asmx, to enable js access to web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `data` to ajax as following.

`data: "{ 'fName': '" +  fName+"', 'lName' : '"+ lName +"', 'Age' : '" +  Age+ "'}"`

Also , you need to use `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` in web service class declaration.

Comment: it worked! alerted data saved, however when i looked in the sql managment studio no new raws were added to the table

Comment: Is there any constraint set at table? That might be preventing data insert.

Comment: I checked it and the data is being inserted as udefined. Any help please?

Comment: If you can debug the web service, then you can detect. Else just return `infoTable info` from web service instead of `return status;', so that yuu can actually see if parameter values are actually passed to web service or not!